# The Security Support Provider Interface (SSPI) negotiation failed

Tags: asp.net, security, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I have error for my custom asp.net 
my code asp code:

```
IServiceConfiguration<IOrganizationService> orgConfigInfo =
                 ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateConfiguration<IOrganizationService>(new Uri("http://crm.tadbirgaranbm.com/TadbirgaranMellat/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc"));
var creds = new ClientCredentials();
creds.UserName.UserName = "user";

creds.UserName.Password = "pass";

using (_serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(orgConfigInfo, creds))
{

    // This statement is required to enable early-bound type support.
            _serviceProxy.ServiceConfiguration.CurrentServiceEndpoint.Behaviors.Add(new ProxyTypesBehavior());


    _service = (IOrganizationService)_serviceProxy;


    using (context srv = new context(_service))
    {
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.thr_FirstName = firstname.Text;
        acc.thr_LastName = lastname.Text;
        acc.thr_NationalCode = nationalcode.Text;
        acc.EMailAddress1 = email.Text;
        acc.thr_Mobile = cellphone.Text;
        acc.Telephone1 = tel.Text;
        srv.AddObject(acc);
        srv.SaveChanges();
        alert.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        alert.Text = "با موفقیت ثبت شد";
    }
}
```

and then when i run this code in my visual studio work correctly but when i run in iis i get this error

The Security Support Provider Interface (SSPI) negotiation failed.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The Security Support Provider Interface (SSPI) negotiation failed.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The Security Support Provider Interface (SSPI) negotiation failed.]
   System.ServiceModel.Security.WindowsSspiNegotiation.GetOutgoingBlob(Byte[] incomingBlob, ChannelBinding channelbinding, ExtendedProtectionPolicy protectionPolicy) +6115112
   System.ServiceModel.Security.SspiNegotiationTokenProvider.GetNextOutgoingMessageBody(Message incomingMessage, SspiNegotiationTokenProviderState sspiState) +1325
   System.ServiceModel.Security.IssuanceTokenProviderBase`1.GetNextOutgoingMessage(Message incomingMessage, T negotiationState) +91
   System.ServiceModel.Security.IssuanceTokenProviderBase`1.DoNegotiation(TimeSpan timeout) +586

[SecurityNegotiationException: SOAP security negotiation with 'http://crm.tadbirgaranbm.com/TadbirgaranMellat/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc' for target 'http://crm.tadbirgaranbm.com/TadbirgaranMellat/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc' failed. See inner exception for more details.]
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +14489026
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +622
   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IOrganizationService.Execute(OrganizationRequest request) +0
   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy.ExecuteCore(OrganizationRequest request) +892
   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContext.Execute(OrganizationRequest request) +254
   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContext.SaveChange(OrganizationRequest request, IList`1 results) +43

[SaveChangesException: An error occured while processing this request.]
   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContext.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions options) +1791
   crm.Reg.submit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +790
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +155
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3804

Comment: The Security Support Provider Interface (SSPI) negotiation failed

Comment: You should put the error message in your question as a clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this error occurs due to the time zone as the server is hosted on some other region which has a different time zone then the local timezone where the web application is running.

to solve this problem server have to manage the offset of every timezone and the simplest way to do it tom manage the time in UTC format. to learn more about UTC click [here](https://time.is/UTC)